# Lock device using DeviceAdminReceiver

Tags: android, device-admin

i am try to lock the device using DeviceAdminReceiver and try to enable administration like following:

```
if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminSample)) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)
  intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
  intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");   startActivity(intent);
 }
```

and getting error something like the following:

> ERROR/Error(1022):
>   java.lang.SecurityException: No active
>   admin owned by uid 10045 for policy #3

kindly give me some code solutions and how to enable the administration permission.

Comment: Please [follow this Link][1] Hope its will be helpful to you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450986/device-administrative-android-app-implementation

Answer (score 8):

Judging by your error message it seems that you may have forgotten to set your `device_admin_sample.xml` to ask for the policy you wish to use.

For instance if in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you have the following receiver code for `DeviceAdminSample`.

```
<receiver android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample"
          android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
          android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
               android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then make sure that you also set your `device_admin_sample.xml` to the following xml so that you can use each of the device admin's abilities.

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-policies>
    <limit-password />
    <watch-login />
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: Is that need root permission?

Comment: No you do not need to root the android phone.

Comment: Yes there is a need to press OK from a Dialog. You only have to ask for permission once and from then on it remembers. Here is the link to the Android Device Admin Documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.Actually I wanna solve the problem that "fail to connect camera service". But it doesn't work.

Comment: From what I can tell that error doesn't sound related to the Device Admin stuff.

Comment: Yeah,before I think disable Camera with Device Admin can restart the CameraService.But I tried It doesn't work.

Comment: Is that possible to disable settings menu ..?

Answer (score 5):

Best tutorial on device administration:
http://rootfs.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/android-make-your-application-a-device-administrator/

Comment: More like the worst. Just checked it out.